# Finalizer Memory Leak or overloaded server

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, axis, finalizer

We have a **JBoss JDK 7** application server in production, that is slowing down over time, the number of connections increasing (as processing time increases) eventually the server needs to be restarted and the cycle starts again.

Using **GCViewer** on the GC log looks like this:

[image: GCViewer]

Using **Eclipse MAT** on a heap dump, **Leak Suspects** shows this:

[image: MAT Leak Suspects]

The main leak suspect is: **java.lang.ref.Finalizer** using **37.57% (501.7 MB)**.
If I then click on **Details** -> **All Accumulated Objects by Class** and then filter by the class name **MessageContext**.
I can the right click on **org.apache.axis.MessageContext** and select **Calculate Precise Retained Size**.

[image: Finalizer MessageContext Retained Size]

This shows a **Retained Heap** of **419.81 MB**.
This would appear to be the majority of the **501.7 MB**.
The **org.apache.axis.MessageContext** class is contained in the **axis-1.4.jar** used by our application.

Looking at the **Java Basics** -> **Finalizer Overview**

[image: MAT Finalizer Overview]

The Finalizer thread does not seem to be blocked

[image: MAT Finalizer thread details]

So my questions are:

1. Are my steps to calculate that the majority of memory held by Finalizers for **org.apache.axis.MessageContext** objects correct?
2. Is the Finalizer holding many org.apache.axis.MessageContext objects something I should  investigate further? The application is a rule engine processing XML messages, sending them from one thread to another so this is possibly how it would look under heavy load. In a separate heap dump the primary Leak Suspect **java.lang.ref.Finalizer** was **922.68 MB (56.17%)**, in that case the Retained heap for **org.apache.axis.MessageContext** objects was **771 MB**.
3. What other steps using MAT or other can I use to narrow down this issue? Is there any way to determine that the application is overloaded, has too many long running requests, rather than there is an inherent memory leak? There are other servers running the same application that are not exhibiting this behaviour.

Any help on the above questions would be appreciated.